# Avoiding eval in assigning data to struct array

Tags: matlab, struct, eval, cell

I have a struct array called `AnalysisResults`, that may contain any MATLAB datatypes, including other struct arrays and cell arrays.

Then I have a string called `IndexString`, which is the index to a specific subfield of `StructArray`, and it may contain several indices to different struct arrays and cell arrays, for example:
`'SubjectData(5).fmriSessions{2}.Stats'` or `'SubjectData(14).TestResults.Test1.Factor{4}.Subfactor{3}'`.

And then I have a variable called `DataToBeEntered`, which can be of any MATLAB datatype, usually some kind of struct array, cell array or matrix.

Using `eval`, it is easy to enter the data to the field or cell indexed by `IndexString`:

```
eval([ 'AnalysisResults.', IndexString, ' = DataToBeEntered;' ])
```

But is it possible to avoid using `eval` in this? `setfield` doesn't work for this.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `eval` surely is the easiest way, but also the dirtiest.

The "right" way to do so, I guess, would be to use [`subsasgn`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/subsasgn.html). You will have to parse the partial MATLAB command (e.g. `SubjectData(5).fmriSessions{2}.Stats`) into the proper representation for those functions. Part of the work can be done by [`substruct`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/substruct.html), but that is the lightest part.

So for example, `SubjectData(5).fmriSessions{2}.Stats` would need to be translated into

```
indexes = {'.' , 'SubjectData',
           '()', {5},
           '.' , 'fmriSessions',
           '{}', {2},
           '.' , 'Stats'};
indexStruct = substruct(indexes{:});
AnalysisResult = subsasgn(AnalysisResult, indexStruct, DataToBeEntered);
```

Where you have to develop the code such that the cell array `indexes` is made as above. It shouldn't be that hard, but it isn't trivial either. Last year I ported some `eval`-heavy code with similar purpose and it seemed easy, but it is quite hard to get everything exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic field names:

```
someStruct.(someField) = DataToBeEntered;
```

where `someField` is a variable holding the field name, but you will have to parse your `IndexString` to single field name and indices.

Comment: Dynamic field names by themselves don't solve the problem, because the IndexString may contain also cell array indices, not only fieldnames of struct. I think I'll need to code a function that assigns the data to the proper field or proper cell by going through the structures and cell arrays recursively.